# Parsing Link URL with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautiful soup (BS4) with python to scrape data from the yellowpages through the waybackmachine/webarchive. I am able to return the Business name and phone number easily but when I attempt to retrieve the website url for the business, I only return the entire div tag.

```
#Import Dependencies
from splinter import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd 

# Path to chromedriver
!which chromedriver 

# Set the executable path and initialize the chrome browser in splinter
executable_path = {'executable_path': '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path) 

#visit Webpage 
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20171004082203/https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/air-conditioning-service-repair'
browser.visit(url) 

# Convert the browser html to a soup object and then quit the browser
html = browser.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  

##Scrapers
#business name
print(soup.find('a', class_='business-name').text)
#Telephone
print(soup.find('li', class_='phone primary').text)
#website
print(soup.find('div', class_='links'))
```

How can I return just the website URL of the company? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a work around like this:

1. Get all the links list and then get index 0 value
2. Then split it with the seperator : "http://"

Check the updated code below:

```
#Import Dependencies
from splinter import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
import pandas as pd 

# Path to chromedriver
!which chromedriver 

# Set the executable path and initialize the chrome browser in splinter
executable_path = {'executable_path': '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path) 

#visit Webpage 
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/20171004082203/https://www.yellowpages.com/houston-tx/air-conditioning-service-repair'
browser.visit(url) 

# Convert the browser html to a soup object and then quit the browser
html = browser.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")  

##Scrapers
#business name
print(soup.find('a', class_='business-name').text)
#Telephone
print(soup.find('li', class_='phone primary').text)
#website
links = soup.find('div', class_='links').findAll("a")
originalLink = links[0].get("href").split("http://")[1]
```

Comment: Excellent! I am now able to return the values from the first listing on the page. Any ideas on how to retrieve the next 29 listings in addition to the first one? the "find_all" command is returning a lot of useless info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead return href:

```
print(soup.find('a', class_='business-name')['href'])
```

Comment: print(soup.find('a', class_='business-name')['href']) returns the website on the yellowpages. I am trynig to return the actual business website such as richmondair.com